# Haben Wörter mit Endungen auf „-männin” sexistische Konnotation?

Tags: sociolinguistics

Ich habe ein Wahlproblem. Ich kann zwischen Wörtern wählen, die entweder „sexistisch“ klingen dürfen, oder nicht so geläufig sind.

Zum Beispiel deutet [dieses Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Landsfrau%2C+Landsm%C3%A4nnin&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CLandsfrau%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLandsm%C3%A4nnin%3B%2Cc0) darauf hin, dass *Landsmännin* weit geläufiger als *Landsfrau* ist:

[image]

- Haben Wörter wie *Landsmännin*, *Waidmännin*, *Obmännin* (gibt's etwa mehr?) eine sexistische Konnotation? Das Wort leitet sich doch von *-mann* ab und scheint damit zu betonen, dass für solche Tätigkeiten irgendwann einmal nur Männer geeignet waren.

Comment: An welchen Adressatenkreis wendest Du Dich? Im Normalfall ist -männin unproblematisch. Das gilt jedenfalls dann, wenn die Form mit -frau (noch) nicht selbst gebräuchlich ist. Landsmännin, Hauptmännin, udgl würde ich ohne Probleme schreiben. Obfrau hat sich mittlerweile aber eingebürgert (Duden nennt Obmännin _veraltend_.)

Comment: @Ingmar an einen kleinen Unikreis. Ultrafeministen bzw. -feministinnen könnten vielleicht mir verzeihen, hoffe ich :)

Comment: Wenn du uns mehr Kontext gibst, können wir beim Formulieren helfen! "Landsleute" (auch schnippisch "ein Landsleut", wenn auf du die Problematik in Richtung der Ultras anspielen willst) ginge, "Mitbürger", ...

Answer (score 6):

Natürlich haben Begriffe wie `Landsmännin`, `Hauptmännin`, `Obmännin` und `Waidmännin` eine sexistische Konnotation. Sie wurden überhaupt nur aus sexistischen Gründen entwickelt: Es sollte in dieser Funktionsbeschreibung unbedingt zwischen Männern und Frauen unterschieden werden, ohne dass das biologische Geschlecht irgendeinen Einfluss auf die Funktionserfüllung haben würde.

Genau das Gleiche gilt allerdings auch für die Formen `Landsfrau`, `Hauptfrau`, `Obfrau` und `Waidfrau`.

Die einzige nicht sexistische Variante ist die Verwendung der Urformen `Landsmann`, `Hauptmann`, `Obmann`, `Waidmann`, die lediglich Funktionen ohne Konnotation eines biologischen Geschlechts beschreiben. Der Wortteil `-mann` bezeichnet lediglich eine Person/einen Menschen.

Comment: Nicht den Verdacht von Sexismus erregt *-leute*. Sexistisch **sein** kann es natürlich trotzdem.

Comment: @Crissov Nur das der Singular von `Leute` leider selten gebraucht wird und deswegen verwundernd wirkt.

Answer (score 6):

Es empfehlen sich immer Lexeme, die geschlechtsneutral sind und auch nicht durch Motion (d. h. üblicherweise Anhängen von *+in*) geschlechtsspezifisch werden können. Die gibt es aber nicht in allen Fällen.

Die große Gruppe der geschlechtsspezifischen Partiallexeme ist kompliziert. 
Oft werden *Mann* und *Frau* gegeneinandergestellt, manchmal *Dame* und *Herr* und manchmal andere Kombinationen, auch mit *Weib*.
[image: Deutsche Geschlechtslexeme, grob kategorisiert]

Nur zum Singularpaar *Mann:Frau* passt das Plurallexem *Leute*. Mit dieser Dreieinigkeit lässt sich häufig gut arbeiten. 
Im Singular muss man allerdings ggf. etwas umständliche *oder*-Formulierungen, selten auch *und*, verwenden; deswegen lieber Plural, wo möglich. 
Das macht auch Artikel, Pronomen und andere Begleiter in Nominalphrasen einfacher, da diese per Geschlecht flektieren und darin mit dem Kopf übereinstimmen müssen, das deutsche Plural aber genuslos ist.

Doppelformen sollten überhaupt auf Differenziallexeme beschränkt bleiben. Das heißt, *sehr geehrte Damen und Herren* ist okay, aber *liebe Genossen und Genossinnen* sollte man vor allem mündlich tunlichst vermeiden, da nicht zuletzt das /–inən/ zu /–in/ verschliffen wird, welches kaum mehr vom /–ən/ zu unterscheiden ist: /li:bə.genosn.ungenosn/. 
Leider ist eine *Genossenschaft* etwas völlig anderes, aber zu vielen belebten Substantiven gibt es Abstrakta, die auch eine Menge von Menschen bezeichnen können, z. B. *liebes Publikum*, oder sie können gebildet werden, wirken aber derzeit noch gestelzt, was auch für Partizipien wie *Studierende* gilt.

Um zu einer Antwort auf die eigentliche Frage zu kommen: *Landsmännin* (oder *Obmännin*) kann **sprachsystematisch** nicht als sexistischer angesehen werden als bspw. *Leserin*, obwohl es die Alternative *Landsfrau* (*Obfrau*) gibt, denn solch ein Status ist eine Frage der **Sprachverwendung**. Sonst müsste bspw. *Hausherrin* auch sexistischer sein als *Hausdame*. *Hauptmännin* ist sogar die bevorzugte Variante gegenüber *Hauptfrau*, weil Letzteres eine starke konventionalisierte Bedeutung als ‚oberste Ehefrau (unter mehreren gleichzeitigen)‘ hat, die *Hauptmann* aufgrund der sprachmaßgeblichen sozialen Gegebenheiten fehlt. *Waidmännin* ist so speziell und wie *Waidfrau* selten verwendet, dass ich keine Aussage dazu wage, aber zu bedenken gebe, dass nur Ersteres von *Waidmannsheil* hinreichend abgedeckt wird. (Allerdings spricht dann *Landsmannschaft* auch eher für *Landsmännin* als für *Landsfrau*.)

Über Bewertungen aus der Sprachverwendung kann man trefflich streiten. 
Eine geläufige Annahme ist, dass eine Bezeichnung dann sexistisch ist, wenn die damit Bezeichneten sie als sexistisch empfinden – dabei zählt üblicherweise bereits eine Person als Toleranzgrenze und nicht etwa die Mehrheit. 
Eine andere Annahme ist, dass eine Bezeichnung nur dann sexistisch sein kann, wenn der (oder die) Bezeichnende sie so gemeint hatte. 
Perfiderweise wird Letzteres mitunter unterstellt, wenn Ersteres zutrifft.

Comment: "Es empfehlen sich immer" -- Geschmackssache.

Comment: @Raphael: Es ging darum, den Anschein von Sexismus zu vermeiden und in diesem Kontext stehe ich zu meiner Aussage in dieser starken Form.

Answer (score 2):

Generell bin ich (als Mann) der Meinung, dass jeder zu solchen Ausdrücken seine eigene Variante sagt. Alle von dir genannten Beispiele werden kaum mehr benutzt, jedoch wie in deinem Diagramm zu sehen ist die Nutzung von Landsfrau in den Jahren 1980–2000 so stark angestiegen, dass ich behaupten würde, dass es mittlerweile fast gleichhäufig benutzt werden sollte wie Landsmännin, und dementsprechend würde ich es benutzen. Des Weiteren beschreibt das Diagramm den Verlauf von 1800 bis 2000, wobei eigentlich nur die letzten ~50 Jahre relevant sein sollten (ja, es gab auch schon Frauenbewegungen Anfang des 20ten Jahrhunderts, jedoch ging es damals noch um grundlegende Sachen und nicht Berufsbezeichnungen). Vor allem dadurch, dass es keine Statistiken für den Zeitraum 2000–2010 gibt (komplett aktuelle Statistiken würde ich nicht erwarten), kann man halt nur Vermutungen anstellen.

Zu der Bezeichnung "Hauptmännin" oder "Hauptfrau" muss ich persönlich sagen, dass ich eher in Richtung "Hauptmännin" tendieren würde. Dies ist nicht ein einfacher Beruf, sondern ein Rang der Armee und dementsprechend für mich notwendigerweise gleich abzukürzen. Armeeränge sind generell eher weniger beeinflusst durch den Feminismus, denn zum Beispiel Feldwebelin ist kein mir bekannter Begriff. "Gefreite" jedoch ist eine gängige Verweiblichung des Rangs "Gefreiter", genauso "Generälin" von "General".

Comment: Soweit ich weiß, hat die Bundeswehr weder "Hauptmännin" noch "Hauptfrau", sondern "Frau Hauptmann".

Comment: Ah, das kann natürlich gut sein. Die Bundeswehr hat bei mir einen Fehler bei dem Einziehen gemacht, deswegen habe ich nie die Wehrpflicht wahrgenommen.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Google can help](https://www.google.ie/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=man%20etymology&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ApGtU60K69jsBv3bgKAF) with this:

---

[image: etymology]

---

> 1. **an adult human male.**
>
>    "a small man with mischievous eyes"
>      synonyms:   male, adult male, gentleman, youth; More
>      a male member of a workforce, team, etc.
>      "over 700 men were made redundant"
>      synonyms:   worker, workman, labourer, helper, hand, blue-collar worker More
>      ordinary members of the armed forces as distinct from the officers.
>      "he had a platoon of forty men to prepare for battle"
>      a husband or lover.
>      "the two of them lived for a time as man and wife"
>      synonyms:   boyfriend, partner, husband, spouse, lover, admirer, fiancé, amour, inamorato; More
>      a male person associated with a particular place, activity, or occupation.
>      "a Cambridge man"
>      a person with the qualities associated with males, such as bravery, spirit, or toughness.
>      "she was more of a man than any of them"
>      a male pursued or sought by another, especially in connection with a crime.
>      "Inspector Bull was sure they would find their man"
>      dated
>      a manservant or valet.
>      "get me a cocktail, my man"
>      synonyms:   manservant, valet, gentleman's gentleman, attendant, retainer; More
>      historical
>      a vassal.
> 2. **a human being of either sex; a person.**
>
>    "God cares for all men"
>      synonyms:   human being, human, person, mortal, individual, personage, soul More
>      human beings in general; the human race.
>      "places untouched by the ravages of man"
>      synonyms:   the human race, the human species, Homo sapiens, humankind, humanity, human beings, humans, people, mankind More
>      a type of prehistoric human named after the place where the remains were found.
>      "Cro-Magnon man"

---

If you look at the etymology for the English, also a Germanic language, word "man" it can mean man as in *Mann* or **male**. But it can also mean **human** as in humankind.

Similarly *-mann* as in *bemannt* is interpreted as person without implying a gender.

Hence *Landsmännin --> Landsmenschin* or *Landsperson* or *Landsfrau* - but *Landsfrau* sounds a bit strange to me.

Comment: Makes me wonder why only the Irish Google presents us such nice tables.